# pullback square in abelian category and derived categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, homology

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an Abelian category. Take objects $A,B,C$ and $D$ in $\mathcal{A}$, and morphisms $b:B\to A$, $b':B\to A$, $c:C\to A$, $e:D\to C$, $e':D\to C$ and $f:D\to B$ such that diagrams
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
D @>{e}>> C\\
@V f V V @VV c V\\
B @>>b> A
\end{CD}

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
D @>{e'}>> C\\
@V f V V @VV c V\\
B @>>{b'}> A
\end{CD}
are pullback squares.

In this setting, it is easy to see that if $b=b'$ then $e=e'$.

Consider a Verdier localization $D(\mathcal{A})/C$ of $D(\mathcal{A})$ at a triangulated subcategory $C$.

If $b$ and $b'$ are same morpshim in $D(\mathcal{A})/C$, then are $e$ and $e'$ same in $D(\mathcal{A})/C$?

Comment: Is not the statement about Abelian categories false? Take (for simplicity) $B=0$, so $e$ is a kernel of $c$. But there might be automorphisms $d$ of $D$ such that $e'=ed\ne e$, while the square with $e'$ is still pullback.

Comment: The statement becomes true, if you insist that $c$ is injective.

Comment: @Echo If $D=0$ then it is true in any category, for any diagrams (not necessarily pullback or commutative), regardless whether $b=b'$ or not

Comment: If $c$ is injective, then the statement holds in any category.

Comment: On the level of abelian categories this is true (replacing equality by up to isomorphism) since a pullback is just a kernel, and localization (here I’m only counting localizations by quotienting a Serre subcategory) are exact, so they preserve pullbacks.  On the derived level, assuming you have a pullback in the $\infty$-derived category (so a homotopy pullback in the derived category), as localizations of stable $\infty$-categories are exact, you can see that $e$ is equivalent to $e^{\prime}$ in that case.  Your abelian case translates to this last case for example if $c$ is epi.

Comment: @LoganHyslop What exactly does it mean that $e$ is equal to $e'$ up to isomorphism? Composing with an isomorphism on the left, on the right, both?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე on the left, pullbacks are unique up to unique isomorphism.  An isomorphism on the bottom and right legs induces isomorphisms on the top and left legs.